# How do you make changes in dynamic languages, and find all of the places that will be broken by that change?

Tags: java, python, ruby

I am used to programming in static languages like Java, where changing the signature of a method will cause a compilation error for every line of code that calls the method I changed. This makes modifying large projects much more easy, because I can make a change, and then let the compiler tell me about all the places that I need to fix.

When dealing with a large project in a dynamic language like Python or Ruby, how do you make code changes, and still remain confident that you are not going to be surprised with a run-time error in production because of some scenario you forgot about?

I've seen my fair share of NullPointerExceptions and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in Java, so it's not like these things never happen in a static language, I would just think they happen a lot less.

Comment: Unit testing. Which is also good to have for many reasons -- but necessary for dynamic languages.

Comment: I always write my code in modules, if somewhere a function is being used and you want to change the function, make sure that output of new function is same type as old function this doesn't cause any problems if a function is changed and also keeping same name for that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas for providing some level of the protection that you are used to in Java:

- As stated in a previous comment, you should definitely provide adequate unit and integration testing to prevent any issues during a refactor. Testing is even more important in a dynamic language than in a statically-typed language. You should check that values are properly passed and handled in each of your functions.
- Use [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and search for usages on a method prior to making the update. This is not full-proof, but does find a good amount of method usage to allow for an easier refactor.
- Do a global find for the method name in your editor or search program of choice.
- Provide exception handling in your functions for cases where the type is incorrect or a value is unset.
- Handle args and kwargs passed into your function carefully. Perhaps provide an error or debug log if you receive an unexpected input.
- Provide [default values](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) for undefined parameters to a function.

Here is an example of providing a default value for a parameter to ensure that it is defined and initialized to None (similar to null) in the function if it is not passed in with a value:

```
def my_function(my_parameter=None): 
    # Do something with my_parameter
```